# Getting keyname in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to get the keyname for a Firebase record when the user clicks on one item. And it works fine, BUT when the user deletes a record, and after that clicks on another record that is below/after that record which was deleted, I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I don't quite understand why is this problem happening. Can someone explain me why is this happening, and what should I do in order to fix it? Here is the code I'm using. Error happens when attempting to call `mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(position).getKey()`, inside the view onClickListener.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Produto, MessageViewHolder>(
            Produto.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(PRODUTOS).orderByChild("descricao")) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                          final Produto produto, final int position) {
            TextView messageView = viewHolder.viewDescricao;
            String descricaoTemp = produto.getDescricao();
            if (descricaoTemp != null && descricaoTemp.length() > 25)
                descricaoTemp = descricaoTemp.substring(0, 25);
            messageView.setText(descricaoTemp);
            if (produto.getReservado())
                messageView.setPaintFlags(messageView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

            viewHolder.viewValor.setText(produto.getValor());
            File file = getFileFromImageName(produto.getBase64());
            if (file.exists())
                viewHolder.viewImagem.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));

            View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    keyName = mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CadastrarNovoProduto.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", keyName);
                    intent.putExtra("Descricao", produto.getDescricao());
                    intent.putExtra("Valor", produto.getValor());
                    intent.putExtra("base64", produto.getBase64());
                    intent.putExtra("urlImagem", produto.getUrlImagem());
                    intent.putExtra("currentUserEmail", mFirebaseUser.getEmail());
                    intent.putExtra("Reservado", produto.getReservado());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_EDITAR_PRODUTO);
                }
            };
            viewHolder.viewDescricao.setOnClickListener(listener);
            viewHolder.viewValor.setOnClickListener(listener);
            viewHolder.viewImagem.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    };
```

Comment: try using viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() instead of position, and put the firebaseAdapter into onResume

Comment: That worked! Thanks @Linxy

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:-

keyName = mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();

As your method accepts values that are marked as "final" if the underlying collection changes, such as the position, then it will throw an exception.

Maybe check the size() or count() of the mFirebaseAdapter before continuing.

Also, try and refactor your listener to remove the final statements if possible.

That would be my guess without seeing the code running.